# Show $V \times \{0\}$ is a subspace of $V \times W$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V, W$ be vector spaces. Show $V \times \{0\}$ is a subspace of $V \times W$.

I am not sure where to start. I know that $\{0\}$ is the trivial set, but I am not sure how that would relate to $V \times W$.

Comment: Do you know what conditions must be satisfied for a subset to be a subspace?

Comment: I know that is has to have the 0 vector, and it has to be closed under multiplication and addition. I don't know how you would apply it to the V and W though.

Comment: We compute vector addition in $V\times W$ as $(v,w)+(v',w')=(v+v',w+w')$.  Similarly, $k(v,w)=(kv,kw)$.  (in all of these $v\in V, w\in W$, $k$ is a scalar)

Comment: Ok, good!  You're covered below, but you're not applying it to V and W, but rather to Vx{0}: the subset you're trying to show is a subspace.  Start by taking two arbitrary elements of Vx{0}, add them, and argue that the result is also in Vx{0}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to show the product space $V \times \{0\}$ is a subspace, we have to show three things: 
-Closure under addition
-Closure under scalar multiplication
-Containment of the $0$ vector.

The last part is trivial. Since $V = V$ and $0 \in V$, we have $(0, 0) \in V \times W$.

To show addition, we take $(v_{1}, 0) + (v_{2}, 0)$. So since $V$ is closed under addition and $0$ is the additive identity, we get closure under addition. Closure under scalar multiplication follows similarly.

Essentially what we have is $V \times \{0\}$ is isomorphic to $V$.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

Define the linear map $L(v,w) = w$, then $\ker L = V \times \{0\} $. The kernel is (always) a subspace.